# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$valid' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

```
<?php
    require 'config.php';

    if(!empty ($_POST)){
        $nameError  =   null;
        $emailError =   null;
        $mobileError    =   null;
        $addressError   =   null;

        $name   =   $_POST['name'];
        $email_address  =   $_POST['email_address'];
        $mobile_no  =   $_POST['mobile_no'];
        $address    =   $_POST['address'];

        $valid  =   true;

    if(empty($name)){
        $nameError = 'Provide Name.'
        $valid = false;
        }
    if(empty($email_address)){
        $emailError = 'Provide Email Address.'
        $valid = false;
        }else if(!filter_var($email_address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $emailError = 'Provide a valid Email Address.'
        $valid = false;
        }
    if(empty($mobile_no)){
        $mobileError = 'Provide Mobile Number.'
        $valid = false;
        }
    if(empty($address)){
        $addressError = 'Provide Address.'
        $valid = false;
        }

    if($valid){
        $connection=Database::connect();
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $query="INSERT INTO Customers(name,email_address,mobile_no,address) values(?,?,?,?)";
        $exe_query->$connection->prepare($query);
        $exe_query->execute(array,($name,$email_address,$mobile_no,$address));
        Database::disconnect();
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: `$emailError = 'Provide Email Address.'` has missing `;`

Comment: as well as at the line of `$mobileError`, `$addressError`...

Answer (score 0):

; is missing in most of statement

$nameError = 'Provide Name.' 
 $emailError = 'Provide a valid Email Address.'

and more, check it

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of `selicolum` mistake and `execute` commane mistake

The correct way

```
<?php
    require 'config.php';

    if(!empty ($_POST)){
        $nameError  =   null;
        $emailError =   null;
        $mobileError    =   null;
        $addressError   =   null;

        $name   =   $_POST['name'];
        $email_address  =   $_POST['email_address'];
        $mobile_no  =   $_POST['mobile_no'];
        $address    =   $_POST['address'];

        $valid  =   true;

    if(empty($name)){
        $nameError = 'Provide Name.';// missing selicolum
        $valid = false;
        }
    if(empty($email_address)){
        $emailError = 'Provide Email Address.';// missing selicolum
        $valid = false;
        }else if(!filter_var($email_address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $emailError = 'Provide a valid Email Address.';
        $valid = false;
        }
    if(empty($mobile_no)){
        $mobileError = 'Provide Mobile Number.';// missing selicolum
        $valid = false;
        }
    if(empty($address)){
        $addressError = 'Provide Address.';// missing selicolum
        $valid = false;
        }

    if($valid){
        $connection=Database::connect();
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $query="INSERT INTO Customers(name,email_address,mobile_no,address) values(?,?,?,?)";
        $exe_query->$connection->prepare($query);
        $exe_query->execute(array($name,$email_address,$mobile_no,$address));// execute command mistake
        Database::disconnect();
        }
}
?>
```